# How can I make a window override-redirect with glutin?

Tags: rust, x11

I'm creating a program that uses glutin, and I want to provide a command-line flag to make the window override-redirect so it can be used as a desktop wallpaper for certain window managers that don't support the desktop window type.

I've done a lot of research and managed to cobble together a block of code that I thought would work, using the provided xlib display and window from glutin. Here is my existing code:

```
unsafe {
    use glutin::os::unix::WindowExt;
    let x_connection = std::sync::Arc::<glutin::os::unix::x11::XConnection>::into_raw(display.gl_window().get_xlib_xconnection().unwrap());
    ((*x_connection).xlib.XChangeWindowAttributes)(
        display.gl_window().get_xlib_display().unwrap() as *mut glutin::os::unix::x11::ffi::Display,
        display.gl_window().get_xlib_window().unwrap() as glutin::os::unix::x11::ffi::XID,
        glutin::os::unix::x11::ffi::CWOverrideRedirect,
        &mut glutin::os::unix::x11::ffi::XSetWindowAttributes {
            background_pixmap: 0,
            background_pixel: 0,
            border_pixmap: 0,
            border_pixel: 0,
            bit_gravity: 0,
            win_gravity: 0,
            backing_store: 0,
            backing_planes: 0,
            backing_pixel: 0,
            save_under: 0,
            event_mask: 0,
            do_not_propagate_mask: 0,
            override_redirect: 1,
            colormap: 0,
            cursor: 0,
        }
    );
}
```

It doesn't give me any errors, and compiles and runs fine with the rest of the code, but it doesn't make the window override-redirect like I want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The override-redirect only takes place when the window is mapped, so if I unmap it and map it again then it works!

Here is the code now:

```
unsafe {
    use glutin::os::unix::WindowExt;
    use glutin::os::unix::x11::XConnection;
    use glutin::os::unix::x11::ffi::{Display, XID, CWOverrideRedirect, XSetWindowAttributes};
    let x_connection = std::sync::Arc::<XConnection>::into_raw(display.gl_window().get_xlib_xconnection().unwrap());
    let x_display = display.gl_window().get_xlib_display().unwrap() as *mut Display;
    let x_window = display.gl_window().get_xlib_window().unwrap() as XID;
    ((*x_connection).xlib.XChangeWindowAttributes)(
        x_display,
        x_window,
        CWOverrideRedirect,
        &mut XSetWindowAttributes {
            background_pixmap: 0,
            background_pixel: 0,
            border_pixmap: 0,
            border_pixel: 0,
            bit_gravity: 0,
            win_gravity: 0,
            backing_store: 0,
            backing_planes: 0,
            backing_pixel: 0,
            save_under: 0,
            event_mask: 0,
            do_not_propagate_mask: 0,
            override_redirect: 1,
            colormap: 0,
            cursor: 0,
        }
    );
    ((*x_connection).xlib.XUnmapWindow)(x_display, x_window);
    ((*x_connection).xlib.XMapWindow)(x_display, x_window);
}
```