# Drawing to the X root window with glutin

Tags: rust, x11

I would like to render a live wallpaper into the X root window. This is [currently not possible directly through the API glutin exposes](https://github.com/tomaka/glutin/issues/947).

I found a post where the asker seems to eventually figure it out: [How can I make a window override-redirect with glutin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45527720/how-can-i-make-a-window-override-redirect-with-glutin).

However, it seems that the code snippet from the answer is not enough to achieve the desired effect: once the flag is set, the previously-created window disappears, but nothing is rendered to the root window. What am I missing?

Here's what I have so far:

```
let mut events_loop = glium::glutin::EventsLoop::new();
let context = glium::glutin::ContextBuilder::new();
let window = glium::glutin::WindowBuilder::new()
    .with_dimensions(800, 600)
    .with_title("TEST");
let display = glium::Display::new(window, context, &events_loop).unwrap();

unsafe {
    use glium::glutin::os::unix::WindowExt;
    use winit::os::unix::x11::XConnection;
    use winit::os::unix::x11::ffi::{Display, XID, CWOverrideRedirect, XSetWindowAttributes};
    let x_connection = std::sync::Arc::<XConnection>::into_raw(display.gl_window().get_xlib_xconnection().unwrap());
    let x_display = display.gl_window().get_xlib_display().unwrap() as *mut Display;
    let x_window = display.gl_window().get_xlib_window().unwrap() as XID;
    ((*x_connection).xlib.XChangeWindowAttributes)(
        x_display,
        x_window,
        CWOverrideRedirect,
        &mut XSetWindowAttributes {
            background_pixmap: 0,
            background_pixel: 0,
            border_pixmap: 0,
            border_pixel: 0,
            bit_gravity: 0,
            win_gravity: 0,
            backing_store: 0,
            backing_planes: 0,
            backing_pixel: 0,
            save_under: 0,
            event_mask: 0,
            do_not_propagate_mask: 0,
            override_redirect: 1,
            colormap: 0,
            cursor: 0,
        }
    );
    ((*x_connection).xlib.XUnmapWindow)(x_display, x_window);
    ((*x_connection).xlib.XMapWindow)(x_display, x_window);
}
```